# JS variable wont update onclick

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code with a list of some items, every item on the list has a button corresponding to that item. When the button is clicked on, a variable `rotation` shall be plussed by 1. This works! But only once? It has to be plussed by 1 every time the user clicks on it, and not just once. Meanwhile, it also saves the information in a database, hence I have used AJAX to achieve that.

My first code I want to show is in a PHP file and looks like this:

```
foreach($finalArray as $arr){
    echo '<li id="item-' . $arr['number'] . '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $arr['name'] . ' 
    <img class="rotate" id="img_'.$arr['number'].'" src="images/house/other/settings.jpg" onclick="rotateObject(this,\''. $arr['src']. '\', \''. $arr['rotation']. '\')">'; 
}
```

I parse the value `rotation` here, together with a `src` variable that we wont get further into. In the AJAX call which updates the database, I want it to plus the rotation with 1 too. I have this AJAX code so far:

```
function rotateObject(e, src, rotation)
{
// Some irrelevant code...
var img_algo = 1;
var img_rotation = parseInt(rotation, 10) + img_algo;


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //Changing the current src from whatever it is, to the src that corresponds to the button clicked on.
            var getEle = document.getElementsByClassName('item' + img_id)[0];
            var imagePath = img_rotation + ".png";
            getEle.src = imagePath + xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
```

As I said, the value get plussed by 1 the first time a user clicks on the button, but not the second time. Any suggestions on what it might be? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Actually I think it updates? It just doesn't know how to plus the variable more than once, when I debug the code, it just updates the rotation and set it to the same value everytime the button is clicked on, instead of plussing it with one? Hmm

Current status:

```
<img class="rotate" id="img_'.$arr['number'].'" src="images/house/other/settings.jpg"  rel="'.$arr['rotation'].'" onclick="rotateObject(this,\''. $arr['src']. '\')">';

var img_algo = 1;
var rotation = document.getElementsByClassName('item' + img_id)[0].getAttribute('rel');
var img_rotation = parseInt(rotation, 10) + img_algo;
```

returns NaN

reason for this is probably that `rel="'.$arr['rotation'].` is "undefined". It says that when the button is clicked on.

Even more current status:

```
    <img class="rotate" id="img_'.$arr['number'].'" src="images/house/other/settings.jpg"  rel="'.$arr['rotation'].'" onclick="rotateObject(this,\''. $arr['src']. '\')">';

var img_algo = 1;
var rotation = document.getElementById('item' + img_id).getAttribute('rel');
var img_rotation = rotation + img_algo;
    document.getElementById('item-' + img_id).setAttribute("rel", img_rotation);
```

I found out that `var rotation = document.getElementsByClassName('item' + img_id)[0].getAttribute('rel');` returns null

Even more current status:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//changes in your foreach loop

'<img class="rotate" id="img_'.$arr['number'].'" src="images/house/other/settings.jpg"  rel="'.$arr['rotation'].'" onclick="rotateObject(this,\''. $arr['src']. '\')">'

// changes in side you function

var img_algo = 1;

//------------please try this (not necessay to pass the 3rd argument this.rel)--------------//
var rotation = document.getElementsByClassName("theImgTagClass")[0].getAttribute('rel');

var img_rotation = parseInt(rotation, 10) + img_algo;
document.getElementById('IdOfImgTag').setAttribute("rel", img_rotation);
```

Comment: Nothing really happens when the button is clicked on now, hmm

Comment: I have added `document.getElementsByClassName('item' + img_id)[0].setAttribute("rel", img_rotation);` to the last line, I suppose that is what it should be, but it returns NaN now. hmm

Comment: the 3rd argument this.rel is not passing the value, please try as stated above

Comment: I have added a current status to my original post, I think thats what you mean? But I am not quite sure? It returns NaN

Comment: maybe it's because I can't get the id of the img?

Comment: if not solove yet......
just pass the id of the img onclick

by onClick = "rotateObject(e,'whatever_u_passed', this.id)"

Comment: I have added current status, as you can see, the `var rotation = document.getElementById('item' + img_id).getAttribute('rel');` returns `null` and that might be the problem. rotation = null

Comment: check by inspecting the img tag if there is the rel value set or not before any click i.e. the foreach loop is setting the value of rel or not

Comment: the `rel` value is not set before the button is clicked on. Hmm. However, the correct value is set to `rel` after the button is clicked on

Comment: I think I am about to fix it now, I'll just sit and try a lot of things, thanks a lot. I will post my final code once it's done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think OnClick="rotateObject()" in this function the third argument value in not updating each time. thats why every time you click its passing the same 'rotation' value, getting incremented every time but the result is same.

I suggest to use an extra attribute like rel="current_rotation_value". and inside your rotateObject(e, src, rotation) function get the current rotation value from this 'rel' attribute and update it each time incremented.

```
//changes in your foreach loop

'<img class="rotate" id="img_'.$arr['number'].'" src="images/house/other/settings.jpg"  rel="'.$arr['rotation'].'" onclick="rotateObject(this,\''. $arr['src']. '\',this.rel)">'

// changes in side you function

var img_algo = 1;
var img_rotation = parseInt(rotation, 10) + img_algo;
document.getElementById('IdOfImgTag').setAttribute("rel", img_rotation);
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I think this could be the issue, but I am not quite sure on how to fix it though. What do you mean with rel="current_rotation_value", where would I need to use that? Thanks!